# rails buttons click counter

Tags: ruby, button, methods

This is another I'm-totally-new-to-Ruby-please-have-mercy situation.

So i'm trying to figure out how to make a database of all my buttons to save the click count each time they're clicked. I started a `new rails` to try it out and generated a `model Button`and a `controller buttons index`

route.rbs

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :buttons
  root 'buttons#index'
end
```

migration

```
class CreateButtons < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :buttons do |t|
      t.integer :clicks
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

buttons_controller

```
class ButtonsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @button = Button.find(1)
  end

  def doit
    @button = Button.find(1)
    @newcount = @button.clicks + 1
    Button.find(1).update_attributes(:clicks => @newcount)
  end
end
```

Now.. i need to trigger the doit method.. is it possible to trigger a non CRUD operation ?
i tried this but it doesn't seem to work
index.html.erb

```
<h1>Hello, This is button and my click are :</h1>
<h1><%= @button.clicks %></h1>
<%= link_to 'click me', method: :doit %>
```

I know there's something I'm not getting here...
Ruby have been doing so much magic that I can't do a simple ruby method.. it have been really hard for me getting the part were methods are taking place without calling them by name..
Specially when I trigger a delete method and the destroy method is triggered by that.. I really need to get used to this too-much-magic coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to improve, I think. Please get back to me if something is not working (I did not run the code)

#### Make your index action list all the buttons

Controller:

```
def index
  @buttons = Button.all
end
```

View:

```
<h1>These are all my buttons</h1>
<% @buttons.each do |button| %>
  <%= link_to("Button #{button.id}", button_votes_path(button), method: :post) %>
<% end %>
```

It's common to have `index` show a list of resources.

#### Only create the routes you need, make increment a separate action

I'd chose to call it "vote". You could also call it "clicks" or "presses" or whatever.

```
resources :buttons, only: [:index] do
  resources :votes, only: [:create]
end
```

#### Add the votes controller

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    button = Button.find(params[:id])
    button.clicks += 1
    button.save
    redirect_to buttons_path
  end
end
```

No error handling here. So this is just to get you started. 
For the next steps I suggest you follow a tutorial or start with simpler stuff.

Comment: I had a problem with the `only: [:index]` syntax but once i switched it with `only: :index` the code worked. Now i know that i have to stick with the CRUD operations.. i can't just run a method randomly